# A finite field subset sum count

Tags: probability, finite-fields

Given $d\in\Bbb N$, pick $N=2^{2d}$ distinct $a_j$ from $\big\{1,\dots,2^{d^2}-1\big\}$ and pick $i$ from $\big\{3,\dots,2^{d}\big\}$.

On average how many of $i$-subsets in $\big\{\alpha^{a_j}\big\}_{j=1}^{N}$ sum to $0$ where $\alpha$ generates $\Bbb F_{2^{d^2}}$?

Comment: Presumably, you mean $d\in\mathbb N$, since otherwise, $N$ is not necessarily an integer.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews corrected.

Comment: Just checking a few details. The exponents $a_j$ range up to $2^{d^2}$, but if $\alpha$ is a primitive element of $\Bbb{F}_{2^d}$ its powers $\alpha^a$ are distinct only in the range $1\le a\le2^d-1$. Is the range of $a_j$:s much bigger on purpose?

Comment: $d^2$ corrected.